# Use any extension for showing image file

Tags: php, html

I am looking for a way to be able to show an images file without knowing the extension.
I found a solution to find an file without knowing it;s extension, now I need the extension.

```
$result = glob('uploads/logo_'.$row['id'].'.*');
if(is_array($result))
{
  echo '<p><img src="uploads/logo_'.$row['id'].'.???" height="75"></p>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've basically written the solution. `glob` actually returns the matching filenames.

```
$result = glob('uploads/logo_'.$row['id'].'.*');

// glob returns an empty array if no matching files are found,
// so we need to check if the result is empty or not.
if (is_array($result) && count($result) > 0) {

    // We got at least one match, let's use the first one
    echo '<p><img src="'. $result[0] .'" height="75"></p>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you use glob, you already have the full path of file including the file extension.

I have written some codes here on the fly (I haven't test it yet):

To show all matched images:

```
$result = glob('uploads/logo_'.$row['id'].'.*');
if(!empty($result))
{
    foreach ($result as $file) {
        if (@is_array(getimagesize($file))) {
            $relativePath = end(explode('/', $file));
            echo '<p><img src="uploads/' . $relativePath . '" height="75"></p>';
        }
    }
}
```

--

To show the first matched image:

```
$result = glob('uploads/logo_'.$row['id'].'.*');
if(!empty($result))
{
    $file = current($result);
    if (@is_array(getimagesize($file))) {
        $relativePath = end(explode('/', $file));
        echo '<p><img src="uploads/' . $relativePath . '" height="75"></p>';
    }
}
```

Please consider I am excluding none image files. If you are sure there is no non-image files at all, you can skip the `@is_array(getimagesize($file))` condition